# Changing path type causes ajax to fail?

Tags: javascript

I found this bizarre, but I recently change all my paths from relative to absolute.

I see that ajax appears to be working fine in the console as I can see the files retrieved successfully, with a status of 200.

Here is a pic: (its small but hopefully you can make out the status 200)

[image]

However, my callback functions stopped running, here is the code:

```
if (config_ajax.type === 'get') {
    xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', config_ajax.url, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            $A.log('succeeded with status 200'); // never gets here
            config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: What does `config_ajax.url` contain and can you look at the specific request in your developer tools' "Net" tab?

Comment: can you read the pic, it is from the developer tools, and it has `config_ajax.url` - this is the exact text string in the variable.

Comment: just visted your site and its trying to send a request to `http://www.www.arcmarks.com/arcmarks/source/arc.js?_time=1389551235054` note `www.www`

Comment: @andrew - not on this end, look at the pic I posted, there is no extra www.

Comment: taking it out of the code fixed the issue however, wonder why it did not show up in the FF console, the console made everything look fine

Comment: well i just checkagain and all is ok apart from the line `http://www.arcmarks.com/http://www.arcmarks.com/arcmarks/source/class.CMachine.php` which has `http://www` twice

Comment: are you using the built in ff console or fire bug? not that is should matter but you could try that

Comment: nevermind I can see the 2nd part now, mark as answer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an incorrectly formatted request to the server as shown in firebug

`http://www.arcmarks.com/http://www.arcmarks.com/arcmarks/source/class.CMachine.php`

note the `http://www` shows twice

Comment: that was a precipitating issue, the original issue is that for absolute paths you have to use `http://host` not `http://www.host`

Answer (score 0):

If the page is at arcmarks.com, it cannot make AJAX requests to www.arcmarks.com - browsers enforce something called the Same Origin Policy which prevents you from sending AJAX requests to any domain other than the exact one the original page was served from.

Also, the comment about the request being sent to www.www.arcmarks.com is right - as the code adds a "www" to the current URL, if your URL has a www in it already it will be repeated.  But I'm assuming this was intentional.

Comment: don't see it on my end, the extra www. realy weird.

Comment: Did you look up the Same Origin Policy?  It is what's causing your problem.  Removing the www from the AJAX URL will probably solve it by making the URLs match.